# Trigger powershell script remotely in an admin prompt mode

Tags: bash, batch-file, cmd, nagios, nrpe

I'm trying to update the JVM Heap Size from Powershell by running this PS Script. It works on the local machine and persists as an `env` variable:

```
test.ps1
& cmd /c 'SETX _JAVA_OPTIONS "-Xms256m -Xmx256m"' | Write-Host
```

But when triggering this same `test.ps1` script from a Remote Machine (through Nagios NRPE), the value of this `env` variable does not update though a success message is returned to the remote machine.

If running the Powershell command for setting the `env` variable (in a non-admin console), like below:

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Test3", "test string", "Machine")
```

I'm getting this error:

> Exception calling "SetEnvironmentVariable" with "3" argument(s): "Requested registry access is not allowed."

So how to trigger this PowerShell script remotely in an admin prompt mode?

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to start the service that is running NRPE (NSClient++?) with an elevated account.

Comment: Yes, i have tried right clicking on NS Client and Ran as Admin but still not reflecting when called from nrpe, i m admin also..

Comment: Let me know if i'm missing on some steps
or if there's anything else that can be done through the script itself
(restarted NRPE server also after restarting nsclient in admin mode)

Comment: you need to setup the service to run as admin